# How do I display a Django Template based on the User's Group?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

First post and am fairly new to django/python. I am getting multiple errors when following a similar thread of how to show different pages for users in different django groups. I created my own context processor in my view but I am getting the error code that the "local_admin variable is not defined.

View:

```
def user_context(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
    is_admin = is_local_admin(request.user)
  else:
    is_admin = False

return {
    'is_local_admin': is_admin
}
```

Template HTML:

```
 {% if is_admin %}
 {% include 'partials/sidebar.html' %}
 {% else %}
 {% include 'partials/sidebar2.html' %}
 {% endif %}
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an import error.  Is `is_local_admin` defined or imported in your views.py?  Can you post the import statements found at the top of your views.py file?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable in the template is called 'is_local_admin', so call it different, like:

```
return {
    'is_admin': is_admin
}
```

Comment: I am not getting an error anymore but I don't think it is working. I have a group called "work administrators" and in my template I want it to display the specific html page for that specific group and then for everyone else outside the group a different page (see my template html code). How would I write it for the specific group I am talking about? Thanks

Comment: Try to check of the function, to find if is an administrator or not, works properly